# Where can I see the Set Cookie header on the server set with express-session?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, express-session

In postman when I make a request to my server I get these response headers:

> **Connection:** keep-alive 
> **Content-Length:** 3 
> **Content-Type:** text/html; charset=utf-8 
> **Date:** Wed, 02 Dec 2020 21:52:10 GMT 
> **ETag:** W/"3-f1UKn0xEFzo3Zk2TjxNV8PkqR6c"
> **Set-Cookie:** connect.sid=s%3AHQ54fVZ7KP9jrPKP1j8Z93O8bIXN0CJl.lTSlYwA48TgarO7MtXGFiG1JL%2FPOHe%2FSGV0cqikGGU4;
>
>  Path=/; HttpOnly 
> **X-Powered-By:** Express

How do I see these headers in express? I paused the server for this request right before `res.send('hey')` but all I got was one header:

```js
res.getHeaders()
{x-powered-by: 'Express'}
```

I specifically want to see the cookie that the server is sending to the browser. How can I see all the response headers in express while debugging?

### Server file:

```js
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');

const app = express();

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'very secret 12345',
  })
);

app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  req.session.visits = req.session.visits ? req.session.visits + 1 : 1;
  console.log(`${req.method}: ${req.path}`);
  console.log('req.headers.cookie: ', req.headers.cookie);
  next();
});

app.get('/sayhi', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('hey');
});

app.listen(4001).on('listening', () => {
  console.log('info', `HTTP server listening on port 4001`);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Content-Type` `Set-Cookie` header is set after you called `res.send()`, so you need to add event listener to listen when the response close.
Then you could see what headers this response have.
But, it's a callback function after response sent, so you could just only look what value sent in this response.

```
app.get('/sayhi', (req, res, next) => {
    res.on("close", function() {
        console.log("====== close event =======");
        console.log(res.getHeaders());
        console.log("====== close event =======");
    })
    res.send('hey');
});
```

By the way, you could also use `DEBUG=* node your_server.js` to look some debug message implemented by other libraries.